Generating Accurate Voltage-Temperature Sensor Equation for NTC RTD Inline-Liquid Temperature Sensor
I am currently trying to generate a curve of best fit for a voltage-temperature data points, where I am given a resistance-temperature table. (GE-1935 Inline-liquid Temperature Sensor: Amphenol). The datasheet provides a resistance-temperature table.
The input voltage is 5V, with a 10k ohm resistor connected in series.
Resistance-Temperature Curve: y = 30329.4e^{-0.0598301x}- I have derived a curve of best fit with an R^2=0.9994. This is used to derive the voltage-temperature equation.
When transposing the function of R(T) using Ohm's Law, I get an equation that significantly deviates from the expected value. The temperature readings would deviate by 25C which is undesirable.
Voltage-Temperature Curve: find in image attached below:


The fit you show is rather poor. Use a better tool to get a better fit.

I would use the Steinhart-Hart equation
\$1/T = A + B\ln(R) + C\ln(R)^3\$
Using values of:

A = 1.1343820E-03
B = 2.3312301E-04
C = 1.1343820E-03

Calculated from the GE Series RvT table from the datasheet. Evaluated, I get:

Considering the sensor tolerance of a degree or two, this seems 'adequate'.
Of course, \$ R = \frac{10kΩ}{(Vr/V)-1} \$ where Vr = 5V by Ohm's law
(also, T is in K, I've converted back for ease of interpretation)

